# Is there anything wrong with having positioning & float?

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have:

```
.event {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
```

It works to my liking in firefox & safari. Mainly float against another element, but be offset against it. I know I can use `margin-top:50px` for the float, but for whatever reason top makes more semantic sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I sometimes need float:left AND position:relative, because the floated div contains elements that use position:absolute.

The "position:relative" makes sure that child elements are positioned correctly within their own div. Without "relative" in their parent, they would be placed outside.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would try not to combine floats and relative/absolute positioning where possible. Just because of the added complexity and additional chance of cross-browser issues.

Secondly, there are valid use cases for `position: relative` on a float. The most obvious is to use [relative+absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) (where the internal elements of the float are absolutely positioned with respect to the container).

That doesn't seem to be what you're doing so I'd recommend using `margin-top`. You'll probably have less headaches that way. That being said, I'm not even sure `top: 50` will do what you expect here.

Answer (score 0):

When using top, the *containing* element also has to be positioned (relative or absolute) or else you won't always get the result wanted. Does that answer your question?

Comment: While that's true (excluding crappy browsers) for position: absolute, moving an element around with position: relative works reliably regardless of the parent's positioning type.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that. `float` refers to what flow the element is rendered in. `position` refers to the anchor element against which this element is offset. If they were mutually exclusive the W3C recommendation would have rolled the possible options into a single property.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea because its position is still in the same place, but you're offsetting it from its original position and you *will* run into [this](http://jsbin.com/ohuga)

You should use `margin:50px 0 0;` in this case because it will shift any elements coming afterwards down properly. You shouldn't need to explicitly set a `width:100%` either.

Comment: How do you know he doesn't need to set width: 100%? Since he's floating the .event element, its width would shrink to the width of its contents if not explicitly set.

Comment: It is uncommon to see a 100% width floated element but I guess you're right, though it would help seeing his actual page.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing "wrong" with the way you did it. In many circumstances, that could be considered the "right" way to do it.

With that said, you should know that there's nothing more or less semantic about `position: relative; top: 50px;` than `margin-top: 50px;`. You should get comfortable doing it both ways, and I'd recommend using margin in this case and as your first approach in general.

Relative positioning messes with how elements flow in relation to each other. If you later decide you want to have another element floated left and stacked below the `.event` element, you'll find that `.event` is overlapping the top 50px of the new element. When you offset an element with relative positioning, its box remains in the layout where it **would have rendered** without the positioning, so it will interact weirdly with nearby elements.